# Are the buy/sell demand, the underlying spot price and the time value, the only factors in futures contract price?

Tags: futures, pricing, commodities, spot-rate

Are the buy/sell demand on the future contract, the underlying spot price and the time value (days to expiration and the accelerating decay in backwardation or rising in contango, coefficent ) are the factors of the future contract price ?

Answer (score 1):

If you include the actual specification of the price semantics (ie, the contract specification), then yes. That's it.